# SharePoint 2007 forms authentification and RoleManager

Tags: wss-3.0, active-directory, ldap

I'm trying to set up Forms Authentification with `ActiveDirectory` in SharePoint 2007 (WSS 3.0). I made it to the point where I can see `users` with prefix `ad:<username>` but I'm having trouble to get roleManager and `adgroup:` prefix to work. Most likely the provider type is wrong. Can anyone suggest right way to do it?

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ADConnectionString" connectionString="LDAP://domain:389/DC=domain,DC=local" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <!--******-->
  <system.web>
    <!--AD FBA-->
    <membership defaultProvider="AD">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="AD" type="System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" connectionStringName="ADConnectionString" connectionUsername="domain\testgp" connectionPassword="SomePass" attributeMapUsername="SAMAccountName" enableSearchMethods="true" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <roleManager defaultProvider="ADGroup">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="ADGroup" type="System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" connectionStringName="ADConnectionString" connectionUsername="domain\testgp" connectionPassword="SomePass" attributeMapUsername="SAMAccountName" enableSearchMethods="true" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [this](http://geekswithblogs.net/kjones/archive/2009/07/17/133567.aspx) article, Microsoft doesn’t provide an AD role provider similar to membership provider.

If you want to pull back group membership, you’ll have to either buy a 3rd party provider, grab an open source one, or build your own. The free (open source one) can be found at [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/active_directory_roles.aspx). It needs some basic fixes but we were able to get it working.